# Why does my function prompt(Javascript) doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, prompt, adobe-brackets

I dont understand why my function only works in the "live demonstration" of 'Brackets', but not when I try to open it with my index.html file...

Thats my function for a password protected area:

```
function passWord() {
 var testV = 1;
 var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
  while (testV < 3) {
   if (!pass1) 
   history.go(0);
   if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") {
   alert('You Got it Right!');
   window.open('/html/ok.html',"_self");
   break;
   } 
  testV+=1;
  var pass1 = 
  prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try     Again.','Password');
 }
 if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
 history.go(0);
 return " ";
}
```

Please help me, Thanks all :D

Comment: You are aware that everyone can check out your JS code to find the password (and the "ok" URL) in the dev tools? Don't do that, never ever. And apart from this, what do you mean with "Brackets"?

Comment: @Lucero my innocence makes me think that he's just trying to learn js, and will never use this in production :D

Comment: @PierreDuc Maybe, but raising awareness is certainly not wrong. Too much code like this does end up in public... http://thedailywtf.com/series/code-sod

Comment: @Lucero [Brackets - A modern, open source code editor that understands web design](http://brackets.io/)

Comment: Its only for a school project xD

Comment: @Thomas Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're refreshing the page with `history.go(0);` which resets the value of `testV`.

I added some console logs so you can see what's going on:

```
function passWord() {
  var testV = 1;
  var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password');
  while (testV < 3) {
    if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") {
      alert('You Got it Right!');
      window.open('/html/ok.html', "_self");
      break;
    }
    testV++;
    var pass1 = prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.');
    console.log(testV);
  }
  if (pass1.toLowerCase() != "password" & testV == 3)
  {
    console.log("Refresh");
    history.go(0);
  }
  return " ";
}

passWord();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s2ejwk9p/

Take out the `history.go(0);` and you'll be ok.

Comment: Thats my index.html what should I modify? 

    <input type="button" value="Enter Protected Area" onClick="passWord()">
     <script type="/js/mein.js"></script>

Comment: I have a file called mein.js with the function and my index.html

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice function.. Anyways, are you actually calling the function inside your `index.html`?

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>
      function passWord() {
         //... (place your code here)
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body onload="passWord()"></body> <!--here you actually call the function-->
</html>
```

This is just one option, which is kinda frowned upon to use event callers inside html. You can also add the function call in your script tag:

```
<script>
   function passWord() {
       //... (place your code here)
   }
   passWord(); //now the function actually gets executed
</script>
```

Comment: Thats my index.html what should I modify? 

    <input type="button" value="Enter Protected Area" onClick="passWord()">
     <script type="/js/mein.js"></script>

Comment: I have a file called mein.js with the function and my index.html